# Is it a good idea to try to compile tesseract 3.02 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, versions, ocr

I have ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook,

and i am going to work with tesseract by compiling it for some computer science related research.

Am i on a good path?

Svn of tesseract provides only 3.02 as i understood.

Should i download unstable 3.03 to be compatible with ubuntu 14.04?

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling

tells that  3.02 is compatible with 12.04 and 3.03 is compatible with 14.04.

I wonder as i said is it a problem to work with 3.02 on ubuntu 14.04

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the page you linked to states the minimum version of Leptonica required in order to build tesseract. So, if you are on 14.04, and if the API of Leptonica did not change meanwhile (for most projects this is only done at major revisions, and the difference of Leptonica between Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.40 was just a minor revision), also older versions of tesseract should compile with the Leptonica available on Ubuntu 14.04.

My recommendation is to simply try to compile it. For most programs this is a matter of not more than a few minutes if all prerequisites are installed.

When talking about prerequisites: The package for Leptonica, which you'll probably need to install in order to be able to build tesseract is called "libleptonica-dev". The other "-dev" packages you need to install are listed on the page you linked to in your question.

Of course, if you don't want to edit the tesseract source code, you can use the "libtesseract-dev" package in order to install the tesseract libraries and header files.

A final word: Usually on SVN one gets the latest state of development (meaning: people are actively working on it, so it might in rare cases be in a broken state), and indeed the SVN tree of tesseract seems to contains a version that is at least as new as 3.03. Anyhow, if you don't want to actively contribute to the development of a program and there is no brand new feature that is still missing in the latest official release, I see little use in going for an SVN version, which, as said, might have serious issues or might not even compile.